# why does col-md-5 not allow image to take full width of div?

Tags: html, css

```css
div.blog-post {
    border: 1px #cdd1cd solid;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 90px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
div.blog-post img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="blog-post col-md-5">
   <img class="img-fluid" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/skyrocket/images/background.jpg">                       <h2><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/2019/09/24/test/" title="test">test</a></h2>
   <p>test</p>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is to make the image fit the full width of the div and make the image as  wide as the border but it is not working and the image is not as wide as the border as shown in the image below:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtilX.png)

I managed to get it to work when I removed the col-md-5 class and I am interested in knowing why this is the case?

Thanks.

Comment: which framework are you using?

Comment: Its look like col has its own padding that why its leaving space.

Comment: Look Like you are using bootstrap so by default there is 15 px padding on the div that have bootstarp class like 'col-md-5' so if your image is larger that the div size it will be resize accordingly if image have "max-width 100% " property of css, And to remove 15px padding for this you can overwrite its css as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="blog-post col-md-5">
   <div class="row">
       <img class="img-fluid" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/skyrocket/images/background.jpg">                       <h2><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/2019/09/24/test/" title="test">test</a></h2>
       <p>test</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

- added div class= row (because of inner padding of col-md-5) if you are using bootstrap